# Google's Indexing XSLT Pages

Tags: php, xml, seo, xslt

My site has been created with an XML as a data store, and XSLT used as a template. It appears that Google is not very good on indexing sites that are XML/XSLT based. Are there any efficient/easy to implement software components that can render the XSLT just for the Google bot indexer? It would be even better if they worked with PHP.

Comment: Belongs to http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: dimitre... i can agree with you on the xsltprocessor tag.. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the PHP XSLT processor.

http://php.net/manual/en/class.xsltprocessor.php

Use as follows:

```
<?php 
$sXml  = "<xml>"; 
$sXml .= "<sudhir>hello sudhir</sudhir>"; 
$sXml .= "</xml>"; 

# LOAD XML FILE 
$XML = new DOMDocument(); 
$XML->loadXML( $sXml ); 

# START XSLT 
$xslt = new XSLTProcessor(); 
$XSL = new DOMDocument(); 
$XSL->load( 'xsl/index.xsl', LIBXML_NOCDATA); 
$xslt->importStylesheet( $XSL ); 
#PRINT 
print $xslt->transformToXML( $XML ); 
?>
```

(From http://php.net/manual/en/book.xsl.php)

**UPDATE**

You asked in the comment how to intercept a request from a specific user agent (eg. the Googlebot). There are various ways to do this, depending on the web server technology you are using.

On Apache, one method would be to use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to internally divert the processing of the request to a PHP script containing code similar to what we see above. This script retrieves the XML from the originally requested URL and renders the transformation to the client. The rewrite rule would have a [Rewrite Condition](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteCond) that compares the HTTP_USER_AGENT header to Google's. Here is an example of the rule (untested, but you should get the idea):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(.*)Googlebot(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.xml.*)$ /renderxslt.php?url=$1 [L]
```

Briefly, the condition is looking for a referrer starting with the string "googlebot" and the rewrite rule is matching any URL with the string ".xml" in it, and passing the full URL to the renderxslt.php page as a querystring parameter.

A port of mod_rewrite exis for IIS too (http://www.isapirewrite.com/).

Alternatively, with IIS you could use an ASP.NET [HTTP module](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/hemantkathuria/ASPNetHttpModules11262005004251AM/ASPNetHttpModules.aspx) to intercept the request, again checking `Request.Headers["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]` for Google's signature. You can then proceed in a similar manner to above by reading the HTML generated by your PHP script, or altenatively by using the ASP.NET XML control:

```
<asp:Xml ID="Xml1" runat="server" DocumentSource="~/cdlist.xml" TransformSource="~/listformat.xsl"></asp:Xml>
```

Comment: The XML is served up to the client and links to the XSLT. Is there a component that can interceed before the request, and only for certian user agents [google bot]

Comment: It might be risky to serve different content only to GoogleBot in case they think you're trying to game the system.

Comment: Sounds more like he's just trying to play the game.

Comment: It's considered best-practice to give Googlebot specialized content in the case of your site not displaying or being functional to Google.

Comment: @philwinkle Indeed; it's being [specifically recommended for Ajax content](http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/), for example. I wonder if that could be adapted for XSLT? Sadly, client-side XSLT presentation is so rarely used in the real world that you won't find a lot of people in the same boat :(

Comment: I added more to my answer giving you some ideas about how to intercept requests from Google. Hope this helps.

Comment: It does quite a lot. :D I should have specified that it was apache php.

Answer (score -1):

Why not just exclude the directory that holds your xsl files in your robots.txt?

Comment: You want your content to be picked up via google, not ignored because it doesn't conform to the expected HTML output. Google isn't going to process or run javascript just for your page.

Comment: Google does process JavaScript.