# PHP 4.3.9 Support For XML And XSLT

Tags: php, xml, xslt

I tried using the example code from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5086894/googles-indexing-xslt-pages). However I get the error:

"DOMDocument was expecting arguments"

I am unable to find the documentation to say what arguments it is expecting for my PHP version, 4.3.9.

I just tried loading the XML string directly in there and I got this error message:
"Cannot instantiate non-existent class:  xsltprocessor"

Could someone point me to an XSLT Processing resource that is relevant to PHP 4.3.9? I'm not able to upgrade to 5.

Comment: I think it's seriously time to upgrade your PHP install and/or switch hosts if that's not possible. I know this is the most annoying comment ever, but I'm serious. :-)

Comment: I'll consider bugging my friend to upgrade it ... [he hosts the server]

Comment: Do it, 4.3.9 is horribly outdated, the php4 branch is not even maintained anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem by upgrading to 5.0.